# How to print output equation as in latex format in python?

Tags: python, latex, sympy, dsolve

i want to print the output of the equation in latex format (Output of the latex code), when i try to compile the following code , it is giving me the latex coede . can i print the latex equation i python?

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
t = symbols('t')
a = symbols('a')
b = symbols('b')
c = symbols('c')
L= Function('x')

deq = Eq(diff(L(t),t),a*L(t)+ b + c/L(t)) 
Lsoln = dsolve(deq, L(t))
pprint(Lsoln)    
print(latex(Lsoln))
```

Comment: Please consider from importy sympy to L=Function('x') are part of the code at the beginning

Comment: If you are using Jupyter Notebook, than you can execute `init_printing()` just after `from sympy import *`. After that, you can write `Lsoln` on a cell, execute it, and it will render the latex representation on the screen.

Comment: i dont know the reason why iam not able to post any questions on stackoverflow.